# Search and open for file

Tags: php, file, search, while-loop, timeout

I have a script that I have made so far which looks for a specified file in the current directory and if it isn't there, it will go up a directory and search again.

If the file exists the script works fine, however if it doesn't it goes on until the script is cancelled for being longer than 30 seconds, even with a counter to limit the executions in place.

```
$path = 'log.log';

$file_exists = 0;

$search_count = 0;
$search_limit = 3;

while($file_exists == 0) {
    while($search_count < $search_limit) {
        if(file_exists($path)) {
            $file_exists = 1;
            $search_count = $search_limit + 1;

            $resource = fopen($path, "r");  
            while (!feof($resource)) {
               echo fgetss($resource);
            }
            fclose($resource);
        } else {
            $path = '../'.$path;
            $search_count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the file doesn't exists the outer while is infinite because `$file_exists = 1;` is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
$path = 'log.log';
$file_exists = false;
$search_count = 0;
$search_limit = 3;

while (!$file_exists and $search_count < $search_limit) {
    if(file_exists($path)) {
        $file_exists = true;
        $resource = fopen($path, "r");
        while (!feof($resource)) {
           echo fgetss($resource);
        }
        fclose($resource);
    } else {
        $path = '../'.$path;
        $search_count++;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** if you're just after the content of the `log.log`-file you can use `file_get_contents($path)` like this:

```
...
if(file_exists($path)) {
    $file_exists = true;
    $contents = file_get_contents($path);
    echo $contents;
}
...
```

Find more info about the [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents) method [here](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents).

Comment: You're welcome ;)

A little note: this code starts seeking for the log-file in the _current_ folder. If you want to start seeking for another path like `folder/log.log` you have to modify the code.

Because if the file is not found in 'folder' the line `$path = '../'.$path` will give: `../folder/log.log`. But what you want is `folder/../log.log`.

To achieve this, you can separate at the beginning the variable `$path` in: `$dir = 'folder/'` and `$file = 'log.log'` and modify the dependent lines: `file_exists($dir.$file)`, `file_get_contents($dir.$file)` and `$dir = $dir.'../'`

Comment: But if the file isn't found `$path = '../'.$path'` is executed, so it turns `$path = 'log.log'` into `$path = '../log.log'` which assigns it as the new `$path`. If it isn't found then again, it just appends another `../` to the beginning of `$path` therefore making it `$path = '../../log.log'` essentially looking up a directory after each attempt until it finds it

Comment: It's no problem if you want to start searching in the current directory and search your way op in the directory-tree. But if, for example, you start searching with the path `folder/log.log`, you finally get `../../../folder/log.log`. But this way you only search in the 'folder'-directory and not also in it's "siblings" (which are in the same parent-directory). To search also in these "sibling"-directories, you'll have to insert the '../' just before the filename like: `folder/../log.log` because this is the same as: `log.log`, and `folder/../../log.log` is the same as: `../log.log`, and so on.

Comment: Ahh I see. As useful as that will be for future projects, for this particular scenario, the file I'm looking for will never be in a sibling folder. If it's not in the current one, it has gotta be in the one above it, or the one above that but never will it have to go back down the tree

Answer (score 0):

```
while($file_exists == 0)
```

will be infinite, because you are only setting `$file_exists` to `1` when the file is found

suppose the file isnt there, then the internal loop will run only for three times, but the outer loop will run infinitely (although without any executable statements)

EDIT:

you could merge the conditions as

```
while($file_exists == 0 && $search_count < $search_limit) {

//your entire code

}
```

Comment: Oops, my bad. But even still, if I were to swap the file_exists and counter while loops around that still times out

Comment: in that case if file is not present, your inner loop will be infinite